# Changing persisted store in redux-persist when app is in background in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, redux-persist

I am using react native and redux-persist to build an application and I have push notification features (FCM data messages). So in order to be able to get notifications when app is in background  I am using below code

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', message =>
  bgMessaging.bind(message, store, persistor),
);
```

basically a taks that runs in headless js my bgMessaging callback looks like below:

```
export default async (store, persistor, notif) => {
  
  //notif -- is the notifications that i get 
  // store is the redux store peristed
  //persistor is the corresponding persistor from redux-persistor
  
  // update store logic is here 

  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

The problem is that the store I get is not the one I have persisted while app was in foreground.
Also if modify the store it is not picked by the app when launched.

How can I get the persisted store in this callback and how can Update it , so that it is it is reflected back when app launches.

I have already gone through few links as below but none of them solve the exact problem

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584880/react-native-headslessjs-and-redux-how-to-access-store-from-task)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603347/access-persisted-store-when-app-is-closed)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also seeing similar issue with my app.

Comment: No @Nikhil , this is an open issue in my app. We are looking to adress it in future by changing the way notifications are handled in general in react native. Using redux persist in the notification flow is not a great idea, we got it as legacy code.

Comment: Redux persist doesn't work in background. See https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1323.